# How to trigger interrupts from a GPIO

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I'm porting a toy app to the [RTFM](https://github.com/japaric/cortex-m-rtfm) framework, and have a hard time figuring out how to trigger an interrupt via GPIO.

```
fn init(p: init::Peripherals, _r: init::Resources) -> init::LateResources {
    let dp: stm32f103xx::Peripherals = p.device;
    let mut rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();
    let mut gpioa = dp.GPIOA.split(&mut rcc.apb2);
    let int = gpioa.pa0.into_floating_input(&mut gpioa.crl);
    dp.EXTI.imr.write(|w| w.mr0().set_bit()); // unmask the interrupt (EXTI)
    dp.EXTI.ftsr.write(|w| w.tr0().set_bit()); // trigger interrupt on falling edge  

    init::LateResources {
        EXTI: dp.EXTI,
        INT: int
    }
}

fn idle(t: &mut Threshold, mut r: idle::Resources) -> ! {
    loop { rtfm::wfi(); }
}

fn exti0(_t: &mut Threshold, mut r: EXTI0::Resources) {
    // never called
}
```

This setups enables me to trigger an interrupt, but there is a SEGV when the handler is supposed to be called. I dumped the binary, and in the INTERRUPTS section the ext0 interrupt 8000058 points to the address 080024e7. I cannot find a corresponding function with addr2line in the binary, so it might be a linker error?

I was under the impression that RTFM maps interrupts to task names, and I do have a task called "EXTI0".

Comment: Unrelated, but I would advise setting the trigger mode (falling edge) _before_ enabling the interrupt. You may get a stray interrupt for the wrong trigger otherwise.

Comment: The STM32 reference manuals are clear enough. What specifically about  them is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Rust, but the hardware steps necessary are:

1. Enable the APB2 clock
2. Configure the GPIO
3. Connect the EXTI0 line to the GPIO PA0 pin (via SYSCFG unit)
4. Configure EXTI mode (interrupt) and trigger (falling-edge)
5. Configure the NVIC (set EXTI0 priority, enable EXIT0 interrupt)
6. Enable the EXTI0 interrupt

I cannot see step 3 or 5 in the code.  It is necessary to enable the IRQ in the NVIC *and* enable the interrupt in the EXTI peripheral.

In C using the standard peripheral library step 3 would look like:

```
SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig( EXTI_PortSourceGPIOA, EXTI_PinSource0 );
```

I have no idea what the Rust equivalent would be.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 ; Language designers always make such claims for their own languages.  You would hardly promote an unreliable, slow and complicated language would you!?

Comment: you know that uC software development is different than the "big computer" one. I have seen so many attempts to make it "simple, easy and fast" - but they all misserably failed. And 40years old good C rules :).  BTW - I have started last year with C++ on uCs and it very promising (generated code is same good as C).

Comment: Rust is certainly not simple, I'll give you that. RTFM is interesting in that it is guaranteed to be deadlock free, free of data races, uses hardware-assisted scheduling and is efficient and memory safe, so I'm trying to wrap my head around it. 

If I wanted results quickly, I'd simply use plain C or Arduino.